# Can I both scroll the chart and drag the indicator in ios-charts ? I am using ios-charts library

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I have been struggling with this for quite some time now. I am making a line chart in which i show expenses by month. It's sort of like a wifi usage chart where we can drag the vertical indicator to any point to know the usage to that day.

The end result i need looks like this:

I have been able to do either one of those fuctionalities.
Translation or dragging only seems to work using

```
lineChartView.data = lineChartData
lineChartView.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(6)
lineChartView.moveViewToX(6)
lineChartView.dragEnabled = true
lineChartView.doubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
```

I have tried to place my chart inside a scroll view but that does not give the required effect either like translation does.

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you typed above works perfect for scrolling horizontally, i.e:

```
lineChartView.data = lineChartData
lineChartView.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(6)
lineChartView.moveViewToX(6)
lineChartView.dragEnabled = true
lineChartView.doubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
```

However if you intend to achieve vertical scrolling or displacement you just make a reverse to the code:

```
lineChartView.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(20) //20 BEING THE HIGHEST POINT YOU WANT SHOWN, YOU CAN SCROLL ABOVE IR BELOW THAT
lineChartView.moveViewToY(6) //8 BEING THE HIGHEST VALUE YOU WANT TO REACH AT A POINT
lineChartView.dragEnabled = true
lineChartView.doubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
```

Do ensure these is typed after setting the lineChartData